# Unresolved External Symbol Error C++ While Adding New Library

Tags: c++, dll, unresolved-external, .lib, blaze

I am trying to use Blaze C++ Library so I downloaded this library and successfully added to my project and used basic functionalities , but for extra functionalities I have to add BLAS and LAPACK library too. so i downloaded these packages **.lib** and **.dll** files. I did these:

1 - Project >> Linker >> General >> Additional Library Directories : I defined the path contains **.dll** files

2 - Project >> Linker >> Input >> Additional Dependencies : I defined the path contains **.lib** files

but when I try below code I receive some errors:

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <blaze/Math.h>



using namespace blaze;


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    StaticMatrix<double,100,100> A;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            A(i, j) = i + j;
        }
    }
    blaze::DynamicMatrix<double, blaze::rowMajor> L, U, P;

    lu(A, L, U, P);
}
```

**Errors**

```
1 - Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol dgetrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl 
blaze::getrf(int,int,double *,int,int *,int *)" (?getrf@blaze@@YAXHHPEANHPEAH1@Z)   MyProject 
D:\C++\MyProject \MyProject \MyProject.obj  1   

2 - Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  MyProject D:\C++\MyProject\x64\Debug\MyProject.exe  1
```

what should have I do ?

Comment: ***Project >> Linker >> Input >> Additional Dependencies I defined the path contains .lib files*** For this you need to list the exact .lib files to link. Also in msvc for a c++ library there likely is a different .lib file for Debug versus Release.

Comment: ***1 - Project >> Linker >> General >> Additional Library Directories : I defined the path contains .dll files*** This should be the path of the .lib files. The dlls should be in the same folder as the executable or you need to modify the PATH environment variable either in your OS or the debugger environment of VS.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for your comments, but would you please explain exactly what should i do step by step. I will be so appreciated. I am completely mixed up by using all ways :( Thank you :)